# jQuery - sticky element is overlapping the footer, how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sticky sidebar working on my project, but when you go to the bottom of the page, the sticky sidebar is overlapping my footer.

What I want is that when the sticky element reach the footer, then stop just right there so the user can see the entire footer.

[here is a demonstration of what I have so far.](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/emvrbG)

[or a jsfiddle in case it is easier for you](http://jsfiddle.net/hdj99b21/)

this is the code:

```
var stickySidebar = $('.sticky');

if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
  var stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height(),
      sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
}

// on scroll move the sidebar
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {   
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 70;

    if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
      stickySidebar.stop(true, false).animate({top: scrollTop - sidebarTop});

      // stop the sticky sidebar at the footer to avoid overlapping
      var sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight,
          stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
      if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
        var stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
        stickySidebar.stop(true, true).animate({top: stopPosition});
      }
    }
    else {
      stickySidebar.stop().animate({top: 0});
    } 
  }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {   
    stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not perfect, but I think it gives you the right idea, how to solve this problem. You just have to check, if the bottom of the sidebar is below the top position of the footer. Than stop the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/hdj99b21/1/

```
[...]

  var stickyTopPos = stickySidebar.offset().top;
  var stickyBottomPos = stickyHeight + stickyTopPos;    
  var footerTopPos = $('footer').offset().top;

  if(stickyBottomPos >= footerTopPos) {
     var stopPosition = footerTopPos - stickyHeight;
     stickySidebar.stop(true, true).css({top: stopPosition});
  }

[...]
```

Comment: but actually with your solution I am gettin the same result @roNn23

Comment: I think you could see better my example here http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/emvrbG

Comment: yeah sorry, my example was just hacked quick. can't look at it right now, sorry. maybe later or tomorrow :/

Comment: but remember it, I'll appreciate your help :) @roNn23